# Are there local testers communities?

Tags: communication

For example, "Australia's testers community", or something familiar? For any location you can think of.

I feel I need to know and speak to more of "my people" :)

Comment: You might get a better response from the Software Testing Club - https://club.ministryoftesting.com/ This site isn't really set up for questions like this - it's more geared towards single correct answers than list-type answers.

Comment: Thanks! @KatePaulk

Answer (score 2):

https://www.meetup.com/topics/software-testing/all/

There is a list of local software testing groups, including the Ministry of Testing. For Australia seems to be around 15 kicking about:
e.g. https://www.meetup.com/Sydney-Testers/

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful @metavaronos

Comment: Please free to upvote and accept it as answered (with the tick) :) @May